# Translation of Kuntres Tiferes Adam

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, internet, english, chofetz-chaim

Is there a English translation version of Kuntres Tiferes Adam by the Chofetz Chaim?

Is there an online version as well?

Comment: What's this pamphlet, "Tiferet Adam", about?

Comment: The inyun of a beard peyos,and issur of shaving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Four Essays from the Chafetz Chaim](http://seforimcenter.com/Chafetz-Chaim--Four-Essays-English__p-11620.aspx) by Yedidya Levy contains an English translation of Tiferes Adam.

Comment: I emailed them in 2013 asking if they plan on translating it,and they answered in the negative. I guess they decided to do it.

Comment: @sam indeed, this is from 2017.

Answer (score 2):

[This is a link](http://israel613.com/books/TIFERET_ADAM_ZAKAN-H.pdf) to an online Hebrew version of the Sefer you are looking for. To the best of my knowledge there is no English version.

Comment: -1 because the answer recently provided below gives us an English translation