# Are there groups that do not trim their beards, besides Chabad-Lubavitch?

Tags: halacha, communities, beard

The Tzemach Tzedek (1789-1866; 3rd Chabad-Lubavitcher Rebbe) in a lengthy Tshuva (Yoreh Deah, Siman 93:  http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1614&st=&pgnum=164) discusses the matter of shaving and concludes that it is strictly forbidden to shave the beard and furthermore concludes that one must be strict not to trim around the beard as there is uncertainty where the "corners" of the face begin and end.  This is the normative practice among Chabad-Lubavitch Chassidim.

Are there other groups of Chassidim and non-Chassidim that adhere strictly to the Tzemach Tzedek's practice?

Comment: Not relevant to your question, but I don't understand what you quote from the _TT_. Even if we don't know where the 'corners' are, why would that halachically bar *trimming*? Only _hashchasa_ is forbidden, no? But I guess I can [ask that as a separate question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)....

Comment: Do you mean do they not trim because of the reason of the Tzemach Tzedek, or do they just not trim, for whatever reason? In other words, are you asking about practice or reason behind the practice?

Comment: I know that there are other groups that don't, but am insufficiently sure which groups they are.  Even if I knew, it would be only from word-of-mouth.  I believe both Skver and Satmar do not trim the beard at all.  I have even heard that in New Square, NY (a Skver community), one cannot daven from the amud if he has EVER shaved, even if presently in possession of a full beard.  The Artscroll Chazon Ish Haggadah quotes the Chazon Ish as prohibiting from hands-on involvement in the matza baking process anyone who shaves.

Comment: It is well recorded that the Babe-Sali was against trimming one's beard. Where "well recorded" means lots of stories where he promised Salvation if they stopped trimming their beards.

Answer (score 1):

Almost no traditional chassidim trim at all. 
On a different note, the chafets chayim wrote a one volume piece called Tifferes Adam where he suggests in the first chapter to follow the kabbalistic practice of not trimming one's beard at all. Its not on hebrew books but its printed in the standard kol kisvei. 
This is a point besides his view of shaving.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/20225/translation-of-kuntres-tiferes-adam

Comment: So almost all traditional chassidim trim some?

Comment: Im sorry if i wasnt clear. 99% of people who call themselves chasidish will never in their life so much as cut a single hair on their beard, even just to trim or even a scraggly one off with the rest. There are other more 'modern' chassidim, if you can call it that who will trim their beards but, say still wear a streimul and have long curly peyos. They are not the standard.

Comment: @user6591, every Satmar chossid I have met trims at least some of his beard, including chazzonim

Comment: @Noach have you been to Boropark Williamsburg or Kiryas Joel?

Comment: @user6591, no, although I have been to Meah Shearim and I saw some folks who were **clearly** chassidim who had to have shaved.

Comment: @Noach then I will inform you that you are mistaken. It's not for me to say who's a 'real Satmar' but the ones who live in the close knitted communities I mentioned definitely do not trim. At all. Occasionally you will find someone that does due to his job. Or perhaps a disgruntled youth. Anyone you may have met in Boston or anywhere else who is living outside of those communities can call himself what he wants and do what he wants, but that is not normative. BTW being a Cantor has nothing to do with hassidic extremism. Usually the ones who are Cantor's are actually not as extreme in their....

Comment: Practices. Hence they endeavor to practice singing in a Cantoral style. Very not Hasidic. Also, it is hard to tell the difference between a meah shearim new and a Hassid. Did you know for instance the Neturei Karta consider themselves torchbearers of the Gra? Very much not Hasidic. @Noach

Comment: @user6591, there are differences in levush between the Neturei Karta and Yerushalmi chassidim. And FWIW, the Satmars I know live in Williamsburg and lost a relative to a hate crime, so I wouldn't accuse them of not being 'real' Satmars, unless you consider there rebbe to be the wrong Satmar rebbe.